# Parting files names and extract time elixir

Tags: elixir

I have almost 100k files in this pattern.

```elixir
["192.168.1.225_01_20190316070000734_TIMING.jpg",
 "192.168.1.225_01_20190316071000736_TIMING.jpg",
 "192.168.1.225_01_20190316072000736_TIMING.jpg",
 "Camera_1_615696208_20190318075200317_TIMING.jpg",
 "Camera_1_615696208_20190318080200322_TIMING.jpg",
 "Camera_1_615696208_20190318082200326_TIMING.jpg",
 "camera2_615696156_20190318080000375_TIMING.jpg",
 "camera2_615696156_20190318081000377_TIMING.jpg",
 "camera2_615696156_20190318093000394_TIMING.jpg"]
```

They mostly in my local drive through which I am doing `File.ls(@picture_directory)`

all these are pictures for 3 cameras, which have an identifier as

```elixir
 cameras = %{
  "Camera_1_615696208_" => "nch1-zcpes",
  "camera2_615696156_" => "nch2-zkhcy",
  "192.168.1.225_01_" => "nch3-ipljs"
}
```

left sides are the prefix before date and time.. and the right side is the identifiers.

What I am trying to do is to make `3-tuple`. like this..

```elixir
[filename, datetime, indentifier]
```

which suppose to be in for one file.

```elixir
["192.168.1.225_01_20190316070000734_TIMING.jpg", "20190316070000734", "nch3-ipljs']
```

I have tried this so far.

```elixir
defmodule EvercamMedia.Nch do
  @picture_directory "/home/junaid/Desktop/NCH"

  def move do
    cameras = %{
      "Camera_1_615696208_" => "nch1-zcpes",
      "camera2_615696156_" => "nch2-zkhcy",
      "192.168.1.225_01_" => "nch3-ipljs"
    }

    File.ls!(@picture_directory)
    |> Enum.sort
    |> Enum.map(fn file ->
      Enum.each(cameras, fn cam ->
        {prefix, exid} = cam
        with true <- String.contains?(file, prefix) do
          datetime = file |> String.trim_leading(prefix) |> String.trim_trailing("_TIMING.jpg")
          [file, datetime, exid]
        else
          _ -> :noop
        end
      end)
    end)
  end
end
```

but this only return a list of :ok..

Comment: Could you please clarify what your question is. Do you want to produce a tuple? Parse the time? Convert the timezone? Delete the files? What would be required for you to consider your problem solved?

Comment: Produce a tuple.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This parses the date from each filename, and places it in a list like your example.

```elixir
[
  "192.168.1.225_01_20190316070000734_TIMING.jpg",
  "192.168.1.225_01_20190316071000736_TIMING.jpg",
  "192.168.1.225_01_20190316072000736_TIMING.jpg",
  "Camera_1_615696208_20190318075200317_TIMING.jpg",
  "Camera_1_615696208_20190318080200322_TIMING.jpg",
  "Camera_1_615696208_20190318082200326_TIMING.jpg",
  "camera2_615696156_20190318080000375_TIMING.jpg",
  "camera2_615696156_20190318081000377_TIMING.jpg",
  "camera2_615696156_20190318093000394_TIMING.jpg"
]
|> Enum.map(fn
  "192.168.1.225_01_" <> <<date::binary-size(17)>> <> _ = file -> [file, date, "nch3-ipljs"]
  "Camera_1_615696208_" <> <<date::binary-size(17)>> <> _ = file -> [file, date, "nch1-zcpes"]
  "camera2_615696156_" <> <<date::binary-size(17)>> <> _ = file -> [file, date, "nch2-zkhcy"]
end)
```

Output:

```elixir
[
  ["192.168.1.225_01_20190316070000734_TIMING.jpg", "20190316070000734",
   "nch3-ipljs"],
  ["192.168.1.225_01_20190316071000736_TIMING.jpg", "20190316071000736",
   "nch3-ipljs"],
  ["192.168.1.225_01_20190316072000736_TIMING.jpg", "20190316072000736",
   "nch3-ipljs"],
  ["Camera_1_615696208_20190318075200317_TIMING.jpg", "20190318075200317",
   "nch1-zcpes"],
  ["Camera_1_615696208_20190318080200322_TIMING.jpg", "20190318080200322",
   "nch1-zcpes"],
  ["Camera_1_615696208_20190318082200326_TIMING.jpg", "20190318082200326",
   "nch1-zcpes"],
  ["camera2_615696156_20190318080000375_TIMING.jpg", "20190318080000375",
   "nch2-zkhcy"],
  ["camera2_615696156_20190318081000377_TIMING.jpg", "20190318081000377",
   "nch2-zkhcy"],
  ["camera2_615696156_20190318093000394_TIMING.jpg", "20190318093000394",
   "nch2-zkhcy"]
]
```

Comment: Mapper clauses should be generated by a macro using `cameras` as an input :-P

Comment: An exercise for the reader. And for me! But I won't overcomplicate this answer with that.

Comment: can macro thing increase the speed of work? @AlekseiMatiushkin

Comment: The speed? Obviously no. Macros do not exist in the resulting code, the AST they produce is injected inplace. I meant generating clauses would make it generic instead of hard-coding binaries there.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Okay thanks, I was kind of waiting on you as always :)

Comment: @AdamMillerchip It would be a huge plus and a favour if you can tell how to do the Macro thing, because I have no idea of doing it

Comment: You do not need macro here. I was mostly joking.

Comment: Small nitpick, this creates a 3 element list for each file, not a three element tuple. I realize the question asks for a tuple, but then shows the example creating a list.